# If an invertible matrix $A$ commutes with $C$, show that $A^{-1}$ commutes with $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

This is taken from a problem in Introduction to Linear Algebra by Strang:

> If an invertible matrix $A$ commutes with $C$, show that $A^{-1}$ commutes with $C$

This is what I tried to do, take note of the specific order in which I've multiplied the various matrices, as matrix multiplication is not commutative. (i.e.. left multiplication $\neq$ right multiplication)

Because A commutes with C, this means $AC = CA$

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
AC & = CA \\
\implies & IAC & = CAI \\
\implies & AA^{-1}(AC) & = (CA)A^{-1}A \ \ \ (AA^{-1} = I = A^{-1}A)\\
\implies & A(A^{-1}(AC)) &= ((CA)A^{-1})A \\
\implies & A^{-1}((AA^{-1})(AC)) &= A^{-1}((CA)A^{-1})A) \ \ \ \text{Left multiply by } A^{-1} \\
\implies & A^{-1}A^{-1}((AA^{-1})(AC))&= A^{-1}A^{-1}(CA) \ \ \ \text{Left multiply by } A^{-1}  \\
\implies & A^{-1}(C)&= A^{-1}A^{-1}(CA)  \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But the problem comes up in the last step, as it not yet been proven that $A^{-1}$ commutes with $CA$, and it would not constitute a proof to assume that $A^{-1}$ commutes with $CA$, when we are trying to find out if $A^{-1}$ commutes with $C$ in the first place. If $A^{-1}$ did commute with $CA$ then we could proceed as follows.

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\text{Assuming } A^{-1} \  \text{commutes with } CA \\
\implies  A^{-1}(C)&= (CA)A^{-1}A^{-1} \\
\implies  A^{-1}(C)&= (C)(AA^{-1})A^{-1} \\
\implies  A^{-1}(C)&= (C)A^{-1} \\
q.e.d \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

For reference this was the official solution, which I'm quite sure makes the assumption that $A^{-1}$ commutes with $CA$.

> If $AC = CA$ , multiply left and right by $A^{-1}$ to find $CA^{-1} = A^{-1}C$

The above only works if left multiplication by $A^{-1}$ is equivalent to right multiplication by $A^{-1}$, which only occurs if it is assumed that $A^{-1}$ commutes with $CA$

But I'm not satisfied with the above proof method in assuming $A^{-1}$ commutes with $CA$, nor the official solution, which I'm sure is making the same assumption. Is there any possible way to complete the proof without making this assumption?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose that $AC=CA$. Multiplying on the right by $A^{-1}$, we get $ACA^{-1}=C$, and then multiplying on the left by $A^{-1}$, we get $CA^{-1}=A^{-1}C$.

Comment: This is so simple, I can't believe I missed this. Thanks @carmichael561

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:
$$A^{-1} C = A^{-1}CI = A^{-1}CAA^{-1}  = A^{-1}ACA^{-1} = ICA^{-1} = CA^{-1}$$
Or when keeping explicit parentheses, as in your question:
\begin{aligned}
A^{-1} C
&= A^{-1} (C I) && \text{identity matrix}\\
&= A^{-1} (C (AA^{-1})) && \text{definition of inverse}\\
&= A^{-1} ((CA) A^{-1}) && \text{associativity}\\
&= (A^{-1} (CA)) A^{-1} && \text{associativity}\\
&= (A^{-1} (AC)) A^{-1} && \text{assumption}\\
&= ((A^{-1} A) C) A^{-1} && \text{associativity}\\
&= (I C) A^{-1} && \text{definition of inverse}\\
&= C A^{-1} && \text{identity matrix}
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

If $AC=CA$, then $CA^{-1} = A^{-1}ACA^{-1} = A^{-1}CAA^{-1} = A^{-1}C.$