# Let $A, B$ be square matrices of equal size ($n \times n$) and $A^2 + B =A^2B$. Prove that $AB=BA$

Tags: matrices

I need help with solving the problem about square matrices of equal size.
I know that if $A + B = AB$, then $AB = BA$, but I can't prove this one.
Please advise how to solve or think about this.
Thanks in advance )

Comment: Multiply on the left and right by A. Why is that allowed?

Comment: Sorry for uncertainty, A and B both have size $n*$n

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your equality is equivalent to 
$$(I-A^2)(I-B)=I$$
so $(I-B)= (I-A^2)^{-1}$. It is enough to check that $A$ commutes with $(I-B)$. But since $A$ commutes with $(I-A^2)$, it will also commute with its inverse.

Comment: Thanks for help, but here is the proof of last part of your proof .. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879244/if-an-invertible-matrix-a-commutes-with-c-show-that-a-1-commutes-with

Comment: @Tigran Petrosyan: Great point, that completes the proof, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Left-inverses are right-inverses. In your original problem, $$(I-A)(I-B) = I - A - B + AB = I$$
and so $(I-A)(I-B) = I = (I-B)(I-A)$ giving the result.

In your next example $$I=(I-A^2)(I-B)=(I+A)(I-A)(I-B) \\ \text{and} \\ I = (I-B)(I-A^2)= (I-B)(I-A)(I+A)$$
This gives two expressions for $(I+A)^{-1}$ and the result follows.